# Get the result (if there is one) of a user-defined SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to get the result of a user-defined query that may or may not return a value.

I've figured out how to get it to work with `SELECT` and `INSERT ... RETURNING` but I'd like it not to break when it's just an `INSERT`

Here's my code:

```
WITH result AS (insert into users("name", age) values('drew', 42))
select row_to_json(row) from result as row;
```

This is the user-defined query:

```
WITH result AS ($USER_DEFINED_QUERY$)
select row_to_json(row) from result as row;
```

But an insert with no return gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  WITH query "result" does not have a RETURNING clause
LINE 2: select * from result;
                      ^
```

I'm looking for a way to ignore that error.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't re-create questions. Expand the original one if you have new perspective on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

returning is required (you are missing).

Here is the solution of your question.

```
WITH result AS (insert into users("name", age) values('drew', 42)
returning name,age)
select row_to_json(row) from result as row;
```